# Node.js deployment to production in windows server

Tags: node.js, deployment, forever, pm2

I'm fairly new with node.js platform.
I'm working on deploying a node.js app to production in windows sever. 
Currently I'm using forever for my production server, and pm2 for development server(just to see how different process managers work.)
What I noticed is my app is down after a while (normally couple days). 
I think it might be because my user session which runs the process is closed.

Can you share with me the "correct" deployment steps?

The steps I take to deploy are:
1. Run node cmd as administrator
2. Go to site root
3. Run forever start server.js or pm2 start server.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any logs that you can share? Running `pm2 logs` (I think) will dump them to stdout, not sure about forever.

Comment: If you're running on a Windows Server you should really be using [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode), its optimized for a Windows environment and it scales your work for you without any additional clustering code. You can read all the [benefits of using it here](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/wiki)